# Power BI - Matrix Show Empty Columns and Rows When Filtered

Tags: matrix, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to build a matrix so that all columns and rows keep showing even when there is no data when filtered.

Any idea?

Comment: more details would be helpful to answer your question, but I believe that the only way to achieve this is by using named columns, rather than `*` from a table.

Comment: @Odeon37 it'd better if u can share what u have tried and provide some details about ur data.

Answer (score 0):

H!

There's an option when right clicking in the field you want to show named "Show items with no data"